# MySQL Retrieve Lowest Value in Multi-table Query

Tags: mysql, join

My goal is to retrieve the recorded purchase price for an item on an accepted purchase order.

`Purchase_Orders` table contains metadata for the order, such as the order number and its status (e.g., 1 for accepted, 0 for declined).

`Purchase_Ord_Contents` table contains contents records, which are linked via foreign key to the parent purchase order on a shared index `order_number)`

For example: I have two orders in my database, one has been accepted and the other has been declined. The data is represented as follows:

```
 =========================================
           PURCHASE_ORDERS TABLE
 =========================================
 id   |   order_number   |   order_status
 -----------------------------------------
  1          PO_100               0
  2          PO_101               1
  3          PO_102               1

===================================================
           PURCHASE_ORD_CONTENTS TABLE
===================================================
id    | order_number | purchase_price |    sku
---------------------------------------------------
   1       PO_100           1.50          APPLE
   2       PO_100           1.50          ORANGE
   3       PO_101           2.00          APPLE
   4       PO_101           2.00          ORANGE
   5       PO_102           1.75          BANANA
```

The query should return rows 3, 4 and 5, since `PO_101` was accepted, whereas `PO_100` was declined and row 5 is not only the only record for the given SKU, it was also on an accepted order. I've tried a few different approaches, but I always seem to end up either leaving out parts that were on an unaccepted Purchase Order, or retrieving the wrong `order_number` for the lowest `purchase_price`.

Here is what I have thus far (not working properly)

```
SELECT a.*
FROM   purchase_ord_contents AS a
       JOIN (SELECT sku,
                    MIN(purchase_price) AS min_price
             FROM   purchase_ord_contents
             GROUP  BY sku) AS b
         ON ( a.sku = b.sku
              AND a.purchase_price = b.min_price )
WHERE a.order_number
IN (
   SELECT order_number
   FROM purchase_orders
   WHERE order_status != 0
)
```

This query successfully returns the records from the `purchase_ord_contents` table, however it omits records of the lowest `purchase_price` that were on a Purchase Order with an `order_status` of 0.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated, I am not very well versed in "advanced" SQL queries as you have probably determined by now. Thank you for your time and please do not hesitate to ask if I should provide any further information.

Comment: I'm not clear on what you're looking for. What is the 'lowest purchase price' requirement? Do you want the lowest price for the items on any Purchase order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be what you are looking for:

```
SELECT sku, purchase_price, order_number
FROM (
    SELECT MIN(purchase_price) AS purchase_price, sku
    FROM purchase_ord_contents
    JOIN purchase_orders USING (order_number)
    WHERE purchase_orders.order_status = 1
    GROUP BY sku
) AS min_sku_price -- this is the lowest sale price for each SKU
JOIN purchase_ord_contents USING (sku, purchase_price) -- gets all orders having sold a SKU at its lowest price
JOIN purchase_orders USING (order_number)
WHERE purchase_orders.order_status = 1
```

Notice this will return several rows for one given SKU if the lowest price for this SKU was offered in several orders.

Comment: This is just what I was looking for! I added an additional 'GROUP BY sku' statement at the end to ensure only a single record per SKU is returned. Answer accepted, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly I think you want this:

```
SELECT po.order_number, poc.sku, min(poc.purchase_price)
FROM purchase_orders AS po
 JOIN purchase_ord_contents AS poc ON poc.order_number = po.order_number
 WHERE po.order_status != 0
 GROUP by po.order_number, poc.sku
 order by po.order_number, poc.sku
```

Comment: I should have been more explicit; this query will return numerous records per SKU so long as the order_status != 0. My goal is to return a single row per SKU so that I may know the "lowest agreed upon price" for this SKU. Thank you for the input, though!